# PHP echo something based on day of month

Tags: php, timestamp

I have written the following PHP, but it's only showing the '1st' date - not sure where I've gone wrong:

```
if(date('j', $timestamp) === '1') echo "1st";
    elseif(date('j', $timestamp) === '2') echo "2nd";
    elseif(date('j', $timestamp) === '3') echo "3rd";
```

Comment: What value has $timestamp?

Comment: What's the value of `$timestamp`?

Comment: Is that not taken from Unix? for the current day? Or have I messed it up?

Comment: Why not simply `echo date('jS', $timestamp);`

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `time();` ?

Comment: Deleted my answer as the initial logic by the @OP could have been used for more than merely echoing an ordinal date suffix but that appears to be what he was intending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what you want to do can be done very trivial

```
echo (new DateTime())->format('jS');
```

or using `date()`

```
echo date('jS');
```

From [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual:

S - English ordinal suffix for the day of the month, 2 characters

Comment: Wow! That's lovely and simple! Thank you very much :)